# Porting Delphi TList.Sort to PHP

Tags: php, delphi, porting, tlist

I need to port Sort procedure from TList to receive an PHP Array

```
procedure TList.Sort(Compare: TListSortCompare);
begin
  if (FList <> nil) and (Count > 0) then
    QuickSort(FList, 0, Count - 1, Compare);
end;
```

and navigating by QuickSort whe have this code:

```
procedure QuickSort(SortList: PPointerList; L, R: Integer;
  SCompare: TListSortCompare);
var
  I, J: Integer;
  P, T: Pointer;
begin
  repeat
    I := L;
    J := R;
    P := SortList^[(L + R) shr 1];
    repeat
      while SCompare(SortList^[I], P) < 0 do
        Inc(I);
      while SCompare(SortList^[J], P) > 0 do
        Dec(J);
      if I <= J then
      begin
        T := SortList^[I];
        SortList^[I] := SortList^[J];
        SortList^[J] := T;
        Inc(I);
        Dec(J);
      end;
    until I > J;
    if L < J then
      QuickSort(SortList, L, J, SCompare);
    L := I;
  until I >= R;
end;
```

I'm not understanding what this prototype means:

```
procedure QuickSort(SortList: PPointerList; L, R: Integer;
  SCompare: TListSortCompare);
```

PPointerList => OK,
L, R => OK

**SCompare: TListSortCompare ??? What is this???**

```
TListSortCompare = function (Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer;
```

I can't understand this code flow.

As you can see http://php.net/sort uses an implementation of » Quicksort - but not the same code flow.

Comment: You don't need to port that code. Use PHP's built in [`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: But not the same implementation of SCompare: TListSortCompare

Comment: OK, but it wasn't obvious to me that you needed a custom comparer. No matter, you really don't want to be porting something as fundamental as this and `usort` is definitely the right answer if you need custom comparer.

Comment: Sure. In the first time I not understood Delphi QuickSort code, but now it's all clear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The closest implementation is the  PHP native function **usort()** using a custom function on callback.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

It's solved my problem. Thanks!